# Managing a freemium application with version control

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I'm writing an iOS application which started off with a free version and, as many apps, offers extended functionality in a paid app or through in-app purchases.

I currently use mercurial as version control for the free app and now that we want to release the paid app as well. I was wondering if there was any way (ideally, though not necessarily, with mercurial) to keep both of them sharing the main part of the codebase so that bugfixes in one automatically affect the other but obviously keep the differences separate.

Alternatively, is there a way of using branches or similar which would make it easy to merge the changes in manually?

I tried searching around the web but I'm not sure whether I couldn't find the right key words or this is not really possible. Also, I never did entirely understand branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you keep both paid and free versions private to yourself.

Why not put everything together and distinguish the two by compiler with specific flags? So it is the 'make free-version' and 'make paid-version' that makes difference.

If you insist on separating the history of paid version and free, I think use 'Free', 'Paid' and 'Share' three branches. constantly merge 'Share' to the other two (or as [Lazy Badger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/960558/lazy-badger) suggested, use 'Paid-only' branch).

And so far as I know, Python uses [forward-porting](http://docs.python.org/devguide/committing.html) and their practices should be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You have at least two models

**Branch-based**

*Two branches*

- Branch PAID branch from your mainline (default branch)
- Add common features and bugfixes/changes to default
- Merge default **to** PAID
- Develop PAID-only features in PAID branch
- Release versions from 2 branch's heads

*Branch per task*

- (Same as above)
- Code every task in separate named branch
- Merge finished branch into single (PAID) or both product's branches

**MQ-patches in single branch**

- Add, enable MQ Extension
- Store core (free version) as before, in repository's changesets
- Add PAID changes&additions as separate MQ-patches
- Implement common changes as changesets
- Add/edit MQ-patches for PAID-only features
- Repository with all patches unapplied will be free version, with all applied - PAID.

Comment: Thank you. This looks very promising. I will look into it and try it out quickly (hopefully soon) and almost certainly come back to mark it as accepted (the alternative being to come running back with questions).

Comment: @mmdeas: I strongly recommend _two branches_. I guess the paid functionality is significant enough to rule out MQ. MQ (especially version-controlled patch queues) is quite cumbersome, and while good for managing small patches, definitely a subpar option for significant part of functionality.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay in choosing - got sidetracked on a different project. I may not have explained well that the features were in both the free and paid apps as they could be unlocked by in-app purchases in the free version. As such, I think using compiler flags to remove the in-app purchase element from the paid app words best. The MQ Extension was a very interesting read though, so thank you for that.